# Making sh script into program

Tags: bash, shell-script

So, my question is: how do you turn a .sh sh into a command line based application? I know it's already executable by using the command `./name.sh`, but what if I wanted to be able to execute it just by typing `name` in the terminal, like  would do with a tool  downloaded with my system default command for installing an application. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have the “shebang” `#!/bin/bash` already on top of the file. You also ran `chmod +x` on your file to mark it executable. The final step is to copy it somewhere in the `$PATH` variable (do `echo $PATH` to see its contents) and omitting the `.sh` suffix.

As you don't install it via the package management (that is also possible, building your own package for your script), it should go into `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin/`. So with this you can place it there:

```
sudo cp name.sh /usr/local/bin/name
```

Now all users of your system should be able to call `name` from everywhere.

Comment: At least on Ubuntu, I'm pretty sure that $HOME/bin is included in $PATH by default, so that can be a convenient place for your own scripts.

Comment: Sure, that is also possible. Otherwise one has to add this path to the `$PATH` in the `.profile` file. Depends on whether one wants to take it along with the home directory or whether other users should be able to use that script as well.